# subprocess.call on path with space

Tags: python

the string that contains a file looks like this in the console:

```
>>> target_file
'src//data//annual_filings//ABB Ltd//ABB_ar_2015.pdf'
```

I got the `target_file` from a call to `os.walk`
The goal is to build a command to run in `subprocess.call`
Something like:

```
from subprocess import call

cmd_ = r'qpdf-7.0.0/bin/qpdf --password=%s --decrypt %s %s' %('', target_file, target_file)
call([cmd_])
```

I tried different variations, setting `shell` to either `True` or `False`.
Replacing the `//` with `/`,`\` etc.
The issue seems to be with the space in the folder (I can not change the folder name).

The python code needs to run on **Windows**

Comment: Why does your path have a double forward slash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to define `cmd_` as a list of arguments not a list with a sole string in it, or `subprocess` interprets the string as the command (doesn't even try to split the args):

```
cmd_ = ['qpdf-7.0.0/bin/qpdf','--password=%s'%'','--decrypt',target_file, target_file]
call(cmd_)
```

and leave the quoting to `subprocess`

As a side note, no need to double the slashes. It works, but that's unnecessary.